# which one is the latest version of maven to use

Tags: maven

I am trying to use maven in our project and am new to it.

checking this https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
3.6.0 version is latest version to download.

Someone was saying there is maven 4 is latest. Not sure where to download this from and can we use this for java 8.

Which one is latest version to use?

Comment: Who has told you that there is Maven 4? Simply wrong. Does not exist yet...So last one is the given in the answer of Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

> Apache Maven 3.6.0 is the latest release and recommended version for
>   all users.

Works nicely with Java 8.  Note that your IDE may bundle an older version in the unlikely case you run into problems.